# On a question about polynomial ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> Let the ring $ R$ define as the following
>   $R=\{a_1+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...+a_x^n;a_i\in \mathbb R,\,n\gt 2\}$ and
>   Let the ideal $I$ generated by $<x^2+1,x^3+1>$. Is $I=R$ or not?

Comment: Is $R$ even a ring? As per your definition, it contains polynomials of degree $>2$, and hence does not contain $0$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan It seems that it is supposed to be the ring of real polynomials with no linear term.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to see this is as follows:

Let $\mathbb{R}[X]$ be the ring of all polynomials. Then $\gcd(X^2+1, X^3+1)=1$ so, we can write $1=f(X)(X^2+1)+g(X)(X^3+1)$. Since any ideal which contains $1$ must be the whole ring, we have $(X^2+1, X^3+1)=\mathbb{R}[X]$.

A similar argument will show this is true for the ring $R$ that you are interested in, you just need to show that there would exist such a $f(X),g(X)\in R$.